# Angular subscribe not returning boolean value?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having issues with observables in Angular. I think I'm either missing something or I don't understand it properly. I am trying to track if the user is logged in or not. To do this I have an AuthService that has a boolean to track if the user is authenticated. Below I have a very simple version of the AuthService and what I am trying to do is change the authenticated boolean. But, that change is not being reflected in any component. I have verified that the value in the service is being changed but that change is not passed on to any subscribers.

## AuthService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GoogleauthService {

  authenticated: boolean = false;
  access_token: string;

  constructor() { }

  isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean>{
    return of(this.authenticated);
  }

  toggleAuthenticate(): void{
    this.authenticated = !this.authenticated
  } 

}
```

## LoginComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleauthService } from 'src/app/services/googleauth/googleauth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  auth2: any;
  public authenticated: boolean;

  constructor(private googleAuthService: GoogleauthService) { }

  @ViewChild('loginRef', {static: true }) loginElement: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.googleSDK();
    this.getAuthenticated();
  }

  getAuthenticated(): void{
    this.googleAuthService.isAuthenticated().subscribe((bool) => {this.authenticated = bool;});
  }

  Authenticate(): void{
    this.googleAuthService.authenticated = !this.googleAuthService.authenticated;
    // this.googleAuthService.toggleAuthenticate();
  }

}
```

## LoginComponent.html

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <h2>{{authenticated}}</h2>
    <div class="row mt-5">
      <div class="col-md-4 mt-2 m-auto ">
          <!-- <button class="loginBtn loginBtn--google" #loginRef>
              Login with Google
          </button> -->
          <button (click)="Authenticate()">
            Authenticate
          </button>
      </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `of(this.authenticated)` isn't going to somehow track the changing values of `this.authenticated`, it's going to emit the value at the instant `getAuthenticated` is called, then complete. If you want to expose a stream of changes to that value over time, look into Subjects. [Here's](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html) a blog post I wrote about one way to expose an observable from a subject.

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted, it is a legitimate question (so I upvoted). You are close to ‘the idea’, but as jon said. A Subject, or in this case maybe even a BehaviourSubject will solve this.

Comment: Ah, thank you, guys. I spent some time reading up on observables and I think i better understand them now (and feel stupid for not doing that before). I see I was using them completely wrong. For now, I've made `authenticated` private in the service and provided a getter, which for now satisfies my requirements of changing the view depending on whether the user is signed in or not. I'll update this post with my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because varable **authenticated** no change stay false and subscribe don't return value and use void function this type don't return value.

> Use **localStorage** this method best to check user is login or no login  .

```
login(email,password){
this.fbAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    .then(async user =>{
 await localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(user)) 
})
//your code 
}
```

```
isAuthenticated()(){
  const luserData = localStorage.getItem('userData');
   return suserData !==null  ? true : false 
}
```

```
logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('userData');
    localStorage.clear();
    //your code  
    );   
}
```

Hope this helps.